# Unable to locate an element by id

Tags: ruby, watir

Unable to locate a button with `:id=>"bld"` on my page.  Looked at many solutions and even tried to generalize it to element vs button:

```
browser = Watir::IE.new
browser.element(:id=>"bld").click
```

err > `unable to locate element, using {:id=>'bld'}`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try looking inside an iFrame

```
   browser.iframe(:id=>'some_id').element(:id=>'bld');
```